# Can I override a route in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger-ui

If I do this:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
 res.send('First');
});

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
 res.send('Second');
});
```

The first call is what works, the second `get` call does not override the first. Is there a good way to change that?

Basically I am working on a Swagger app where it can hit multiple APIs. I forked from https://github.com/thanhson1085/swagger-combined. The app knows if API A hits `/user` it will proxy any calls from `/user` to the appropriate place. Right now the app lists all API calls from as many APIs as you load. That means if API A & API B have the same endpoint of `/user`, I will only ever proxy to the first API that registered the endpoint in my app.

Comment: It would be good to leave a comment as to why you downvoted me, anonymous downvoter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Express does not allow to override routes. But you should be able to use one and decide where to proxy those calls.

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  if(req.isFirst()){
    res.send('First');
  }
  if(req.isSecond()){
    res.send('Second');
  }
});
```

It would probably better to have those apis in separate endpoints like `/api1/user/` and `api2/user/`.

You can basically pass Express Router into another Express Router.

```
let api1Router = express.Router()
rootRouter.use('/api1', api1Router)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not in control of endpoints here. I am just aggregating other folks' APIs.

Comment: Do you have those APIs available separately? or you will be using proxy to pass the requests further?

Comment: I'm using a proxy so that if api endpoint is `/user` i hit `/user` on my server, via that open source repo. However I want to tweak it so `/user` route may go to one domain or another. If I can't overwrite, which seems to be the case, I'll have to register more info and make the proxy smarter. I may end up doing that (the more complex version of first vs second in your answer)

Answer (score 2):

I sort of creating a framework currently using express and part of it is the have default routing.
But I also need to on occasion replace the default routing.
Turned out that it was not superhard to do, it's just a matter of moving the default route to the end, and then, if anything else get a hit before it will be used instead.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
// default rout
router.all('/:path(\\d+|\\w+)?', (req, res, next) => {
}
// Route I want to be used first
router.get('/list', (req, res, next) => {
}
// move default route to end of stack
const stack = router.stack;
for(let i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
  if(i < stack.length -1 && stack[i].regexp.toString() === '/^(?:\\/(\\d+|\\w+))?\\/?$/i' && stack[i].route.methods._all) {
    stack.push(stack.splice(i, 1)[0]);
  }
}
```